# How to create a popup after customer logs in

Tags: javascript, magento2.4.3, modal-popup, customer-login, loginpopup

I am new to Magento..I have successfully created a popup using modal widget in customer_account_index.xml, but this popup works only when customer clicks on My account tab.  I am looking for complete code that will show a popup with customerId.  Once user clicks the popup, it should redirect to a specific url.  Following code is not useful to me now as I need the popup only once right after the user logs in.  I have researched about customer_login event, but none of the solutions worked for me.

My phtml file looks like this

`````
<div id="modal-content"></div>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function($, modal) {
            let customerId = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
            alert(customerId);
            const ajaxUrl = customurl;
            const redirectUrl = redirecturl;
            const title = sometitle;
                        let options = {
                            type: 'popup',
                            responsive: true,
                            innerScroll: true,
                            title: title,
                            buttons: [{
                                text: $.mage.__('OK'),
                                class: 'modal-close',
                                textalign: 'center',
                                click: function (){
                                    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
                                    this.closeModal();
                                }
                            }]
                        };

                        modal(options, $('#modal-content'));
                        $( window ).load(function() {
                            $("#modal-content").modal("openModal");
                        });
                    }
                }
        });````
`````

Comment: in which file you added this code?

Comment: In customer_account_index.xml, I mentioned a phtml file, in that I added this code

Comment: are you still looking for a help or you have already fixed the problem? @Siri

Comment: Hello @Siri , I have added a answer and also tested in my system it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This solution is implemented in a way that it does not get affected due to Magento page caching.**

**Follow the below steps**

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/registration.php** to register the module.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Tarun_StackOverflow', __DIR__);
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/etc/module.xml** to declare the module name, version and dependencies if there is any.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Tarun_StackOverflow" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/etc/adminhtml/system.xml** to add the store configuration.

**1.) I have added configuration to enable and disable login popup feature.**

**2.) I have added feature whether to display popup on each login or only first time customer login only.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="login_popup" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Login Popup</label>
            <tab>customer</tab>
            <resource>Magento_Customer::config_customer</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="show_on_every_login" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Display Popup On Each Login</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/etc/config.xml** to define default configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <login_popup>
            <general>
                <enable>1</enable>
                <show_on_every_login>1</show_on_every_login>
            </general>
        </login_popup>
    </default>
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/Helper/Data.php** to retrieve store configuration.

```
<?php


namespace Tarun\StackOverflow\Helper;


use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

/**
 * Class Data
 * @package Tarun\StackOverflow\Helper
 */
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * Config path to get setting for whether to show popup on each login
     */
    const XML_CONFIG_PATH = 'login_popup/general/show_on_every_login';

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getShowPopupOnEachLoginConfig()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_CONFIG_PATH,ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/etc/di.xml** to define plugin to intercept the login action and set the required cookie.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Session">
        <plugin name="setLoginPopupCookie" type="Tarun\StackOverflow\Model\Plugin\SetLoginPopupCookie" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/Model/Plugin/SetLoginPopupCookie.php** to write plugin code.

```
<?php


namespace Tarun\StackOverflow\Model\Plugin;


use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieSizeLimitReachedException;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Tarun\StackOverflow\Helper\Data as PopupHelper;


/**
 * Class SetLoginPopupCookie
 * @package Tarun\StackOverflow\Model\Plugin
 */
class SetLoginPopupCookie
{
    /**
     * @var CookieManagerInterface
     */
    private CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private CustomerRepositoryInterface $_customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var PopupHelper
     */
    private PopupHelper $popupHelper;

    /**
     * SetLoginPopupCookie constructor.
     * @param CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
     * @param CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param PopupHelper $popupHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        PopupHelper $popupHelper
    ) {
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->popupHelper = $popupHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterSetCustomerDataAsLoggedIn(Session $customerSession, $result)
    {
        $publicCookieMetadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata();
        $publicCookieMetadata->setDurationOneYear();
        $publicCookieMetadata->setPath('/');
        $publicCookieMetadata->setHttpOnly(false);

        try {
            $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerSession->getCustomerId());
            if($customer->getId()) {
                $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('can_show_login_popup', "1", $publicCookieMetadata);

                $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('show_popup_on_each_config', $this->popupHelper->getShowPopupOnEachLoginConfig(), $publicCookieMetadata);
                if($this->cookieManager->getCookie('displayed_login_popup') === "1" && !$this->popupHelper->getShowPopupOnEachLoginConfig()) {
                    $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('displayed_login_popup', "1", $publicCookieMetadata);
                } else {
                    $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('displayed_login_popup', "0", $publicCookieMetadata);
                }
            } else {
                $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('can_show_login_popup', "0", $publicCookieMetadata);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            // Here you can log the error if you want that no customer exist
            try {
                $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('can_show_login_popup', "0", $publicCookieMetadata);
            } catch (InputException $e) {
                // Here you can log input related error
            } catch (CookieSizeLimitReachedException $e) {
                // Here you can log Cookie's size limit related error
            } catch (FailureToSendException $e) {
                // Here you can log failure send related error
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            // Here you can log the error
            try {
                $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('can_show_login_popup', "0", $publicCookieMetadata);
            } catch (InputException $e) {
                // Here you can log input related error
            } catch (CookieSizeLimitReachedException $e) {
                // Here you can log Cookie's size limit related error
            } catch (FailureToSendException $e) {
                // Here you can log failure send related error
            }
        } catch (InputException $e) {
            // Here you can log input related error
        } catch (CookieSizeLimitReachedException $e) {
            // Here you can log Cookie's size limit related error
        } catch (FailureToSendException $e) {
            // Here you can log failure send related error
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/view/frontend/layout/default.xml** to call your block.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:View/Layout:etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="login-popup" template="Tarun_StackOverflow::login_popup.phtml" ifconfig="login_popup/general/enable" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/view/frontend/templates/login_popup.phtml** to add your template content.

```
<div id="modal-container" data-bind="scope:'login-popup'" >
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
           "components": {
                "login-popup": {
                    "component": "Tarun_StackOverflow/js/login_popup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/view/frontend/web/js/login_popup.js** to add you javascript login.

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'underscore',
    'mage/cookies'
], function (ko, Component, $, modal, _) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        templateToRender: 'Tarun_StackOverflow/template/login_popup.html',
        renderer: null,
        data: {"name": "Tarun", "module": "StackOverflow"},
        initialize: function (config) {
            this._super();
            let options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Login Popup',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('OK'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };
            require(['text!' + this.templateToRender], function (templateContents) {
                this.renderer = _.template(templateContents);
                let self = this;
                let data = self.data;
                if(self.showPopup()) {
                    modal({
                        title: $.mage.__('Login Popup'),
                        content: self.render({data}),
                        modalClass: 'confirm login-confirm',
                        actions: {
                            cancel: function(){
                                $.mage.cookies.set('can_show_login_popup', '0', {
                                    samesite: 'strict',
                                    domain: ''
                                });
                                if($.mage.cookies.get('show_popup_on_each_config') === "0") {
                                    $.mage.cookies.set('displayed_login_popup', '1', {
                                        samesite: 'strict',
                                        domain: ''
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            always: function(){}
                        },
                        buttons: [{
                            text: $.mage.__('Cancel'),
                            class: 'action-secondary action-dismiss',
                            click: function (event) {
                                this.closeModal(event);
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                }
            }.bind(this));
        },
        render: function (data) {
            return this.renderer(data);
        },
        showPopup: function () {
            return $.mage.cookies.get('can_show_login_popup') === "1" && $.mage.cookies.get('displayed_login_popup') === "0";
        }
    });
});
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/view/frontend/web/template/login_popup.html** to add the popup content and print your variables from javascript file.

```
<div id="modal-content">
    <div>Hello <%- data.name %>, This is your modal popup content in module <%- data.module %></div>
</div>
```

**Output**
[image]

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**

Comment: Thanks...For now, I implemented a solution myself by creating a customer login event and observer where observer calls a helper.  Helper creates a cookie.  I moved my code from customer_account_index.xml to default.xml and added code to call a block and phtml.  Depending on whether cookie is set or not, phtml popup if displayed.

Comment: Will check your solution and definitely accept as answer once I test it on my own

Comment: Thank you @Siri, you can also render dynamic data in popup by calling any APIs from js and set data there, which can be rendered in HTML file. In my code I set static data that is name and module name.

Comment: I tested this now, but the popup doesnt showup.  I verified in setup_module to see if module is created.  I also checked if your cookies are created, display popup cookie is always 0.  I tried to put an alert in the js file before return component, no alert comes after login, so looks like js isnt called at all.  I verified file names, paths everything seem fine

Comment: okay, I changed the following in default.xml and it worked.. <referenceContainer name="footer"> to  <referenceContainer name="content"> somehow footer dint work for me

Comment: Great @Siri, Happy to know that it worked for you.